# iOS Shared Credentials: Check if user selected "Do not save passwords" in Safari

Tags: ios, authentication, ios9

We are using Shared Credentials in our iOS App. The workflow is this:

1. User logs in on our website in Safari.
2. Safari asks *"Save Password?"*
3. User selects *"Yes"*
4. User launches our app, navigates to login
5. iOS shows a popup where user can select the account.
6. We query shared credentials previously entered in Safari, and log user in.

This works fine.

However, if use selects *"Never for this website"* in step 3, then in step 5, he can select an entry that says *"Passwords not saved"*.

And if he does that, we get a username *"Passwords not saved"*, and a password *" "*.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

e.g. Can we check before we call the

```
public func SecRequestSharedWebCredential(fqdn: CFString?, _ account: CFString?, _ completionHandler: (CFArray?, CFError?) -> Void)
```

-method, if the user has declined to save his password in Safari?

Comment: Can confirm, I also have the same problem.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/logon) with Apple; if others have the same issue, it's [advisable to do the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/145223/1803879)